# How to generate QRCode with centre logo using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, qr-code

I need to generate QR codes on the backend.
Using this lib [qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode)

I can generate SVG on the backend and return by API. For the logo, I found this lib [qrcode-with-logos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode-with-logos) but lib uses canvas for this. How can I implement this on the backend?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwpzK.png)

Comment: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-with-logo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qr-with-logo)